# How to make a "this link need to be opened in a program" link (windows registry)

Tags: windows, nsis

I have tried to get this to work many hours now. It is almust working.
My situation is that i'm creating a installer with nsis and would like to make a link like skype (call & skype) and steam (steam://join/214456146) that will launch my program with some arguments.

The problem is i can't get it to send the arguments from the link to the program.
The program works normally if i run it with the cmd.

Here is the part of my nsis code that (tries) to register something in the registry:

```
WriteRegStr HKCR "AudioOmega" "" "URL:AudioOmega Game Protocol"
WriteRegStr HKCR "AudioOmega" "URL Protocol" ""
WriteRegStr HKCR "AudioOmega\DefaultIcon" "" "$INSTDIR\game-controller.exe,1"
WriteRegStr HKCR "AudioOmega\shell" "" "open"
WriteRegStr HKCR "AudioOmega\shell\open\command" "" "$INSTDIR\game-controller.exe %1 %2 %3"
```

Another problem is that when i click a link with my custom protocol name (audioomega://parms) it comes up with the dialog but it doesn't say AudioOmega Game Controller it sayes the path of the script + %1, %2 and %3

Answer (score 2):

You failed to specify which dialog you are talking about! All the mainstream browsers have their own implementation of the dialog that comes up when you click a protocol link. The Windows shell does not display any dialog when you invoke it directly.

When invoking using ShellExecute you can specify extra parameters but for something started by a browser you need to put everything in the URI because only %1 is used by most implementations.

Internet Explorer uses the `FriendlyAppName` value as the app name if present:

```
Page Components
Page InstFiles

!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
${GetParameters} $0
${GetOptions} $0 "/uri=" $1
${IfNot} ${Errors}
    MessageBox MB_OK "Started as protocol.$\n$\nCommand line=$0"
    Quit
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section "Register protocol" ; This example uses HKCU\Software\Classes and not HKCR so it works as non-admin
WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Classes\TestProto" "" "URL:TestProto Protocol"
WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Classes\TestProto" "FriendlyTypeName" "TestProto protocol"
WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Classes\TestProto" "URL Protocol" ""
; Optional: UseOriginalUrlEncoding
WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "Software\Classes\TestProto\DefaultIcon" "" "%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,6"
WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Classes\TestProto\shell" "" "open"
WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Classes\TestProto\shell\open" "FriendlyAppName" "Test app for TestProto protocol"
WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Classes\TestProto\shell\open\command" "" '"$exepath" /uri="%1" /params="%2 %3 %4"'
SectionEnd

Section "Test protocol"
ExecShell "" "testproto://foo/bar?a=b&c=d" '1 "t w o" 3'
InitPluginsDir
FileOpen $0 "$PluginsDir\test.html" w
FileWrite $0 '<html><body><a href="testproto://hello/world?a=b&c=d">Test</a></body></html>'
FileClose $0
ExecShell "" "$PluginsDir\test.html"
SectionEnd

Section "Unregister protocol"
MessageBox MB_OK "Click OK to remove the protocol handler..."
DeleteRegKey HKCU "Software\Classes\TestProto"
SectionEnd
```